# How to Press 3 Keys at a Time using KeyPress?

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

Is it possible to get 3 keys at time on `KeyPress`?
I want to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> . . .

I tried the ff:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.H && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.T && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("^");
    }
}
```

But seems not work. I guess e.KeyCode returns only one key at a time? So I'm still thinking on how I can do it ... or storing previous key to variable possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably the only 100% reliable way to do this is to call the [GetAsyncKeyState](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate) API function. See also the MSDN article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (I tested it and it seems to do what you need).

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, it sets a boolean variable. Then if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> immediately afterwards, it'll detect that both were pressed in succession. If you press anything other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, it'll set the flag back to False.

```
private bool isCtrlHPressed;

private void txt_callerName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (isCtrlHPressed && e.KeyCode == Keys.T && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        Console.WriteLine("^");

    isCtrlHPressed = (e.KeyCode == Keys.H && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control);
}
```

Comment: ill accept this for i found this the simplest answer . thanks @GrantWinney

Comment: What if you press Ctrl+H, then let up on the H and then press the T? I think you'll need a `KeyUp` event handler to handle that case. And even then it can probably be fooled.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Keys key1 = Keys.None;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (key1 == Keys.H && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode != Keys.ControlKey)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Key Pressed");
        key1 = Keys.None;
    }
    else if (e.Control && key1 == Keys.None && e.KeyCode != Keys.ControlKey)
        key1 = e.KeyCode;
    else if (e.Control)
        key1 = Keys.None;
}
```

Comment: i just notice every time i press ctrl + H + anykey and it worked ... how about specifying if 2nd key was T?

Comment: you can add another condition `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.T)` in your first if condition.

Comment: +1 for it worked but i see the simplest answer by @GrantWinney
still thanks a lot mate .

Comment: This will fail if the user presses Ctrl+H, releases the H, and then presses T. It will report all three keys down when in fact the H has been released.

Comment: @JimMischel if you have any solution please post it. Promise i will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X && e.Control && e.Shift) {
        // CTRL+SHIFT+X was pressed!
    }
```

Comment: you should read question carefully before posting an answer otherwise you may get down votes. OP wants to multiple key with single modifier just like Visual Studio Code Beautifier `Ctrl + K + D`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.H && e.KeyCode == Keys.T)
{
    Console.WriteLine("^");
}
```

**OR** try this one also

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.H && e.KeyCode == Keys.T) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("^");
}
```

Comment: awesome..!! can you tell me how can you store two keys in a single `Keys` type object?